# PCA on correlation matrix in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Does anyone know how to perform PCA using PL/pgSQL in a PostgreSQL function, considering correlation matrixes of potentially high order? Maybe a specific library for this problem.

Comment: Are you prepared to use PL/R? R would be the obvious choice for PCA?

Comment: Thanks, John. I need to use R and PostgreSQL due to integration with existing software. I will analyze the use of PL/R.